# error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis?

Tags: oracle

I have been looking at this code for the past two days now and I can not seem to get it to work. It keeps giving me

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

I know that this is a topic that comes up a lot but for some reason none of the examples I have seen has helped me. Can someone please tell me why I got this error and how do I fix it? I am pretty sure that it has nothing to do with my parenthesis, maybe it's my CONSTRAINTS?

```
CREATE TABLE General_STAFF(
GS_PEOPLE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
Dept_Id NUMBER NOT NULL,
staff_type varchar2(30),
staff_salary int,
date_hired date,
CONSTRAINT general_staff_pk PRIMARY KEY(GS_PEOPLE_ID) REFERENCES PEOPLE(PEOPLE_ID),
CONSTRAINT general_staff_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_ID)
);
```

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(GS_PEOPLE_ID)` should be `foreign key (...)`

Comment: and then you might replace the first `NOT NULL` with `PRIMARY KEY` .

Comment: There is syntactical error in your table definition and my suggestion will be to read about primary key and foreign key definition. Read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-primary-key-and-foreign-key/

My purpose is not to give an answer but to tell ,you will definitely get your answer afterwards. Cheers and best of luck

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan: given as comments now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PRIMARY KEY must not reference anything

so I think that you want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE General_STAFF(
GS_PEOPLE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
Dept_Id NUMBER NOT NULL,
staff_type varchar2(30),
staff_salary int,
date_hired date,
CONSTRAINT general_staff_pk primary key ( GS_PEOPLE_ID , Dept_Id),
CONSTRAINT general_staff_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(GS_PEOPLE_ID) REFERENCES PEOPLE(PEOPLE_ID),
CONSTRAINT general_staff_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_ID)
);
```